# returning an address of a local variable

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, local-variables

'''

```
        int* fun(){
        int x=5;
        int* p=&x;
        return p;//problematic part 
        }
    int main(){
    int *c=p;    //error when int "*c=&x;"
*c=13;
    }
```

'''

when I create a "integer pointer" in the main function and then assign the address of a local variable to that " integer pointer" through the pointer p , and  assign a new value to that particular address, it doesn't give any error or warning ,which I think it should. because when I tried to return the address of "int x" through "&x"  and then try to change the value of it, program crashed as I expected.

why does  the program not crash any error when I use "pointer p"?????
edit: program should have crashed that's my question not that the reason why compiler gave warnings

Comment: It's undefined behavior, anything can happen. It might crash, it might not.

Comment: the problem is that proving that something points to a local object/doesn't equates to the halting problem, so compilers do not even try and they usually just warn in the very obvious cases where it is 1000 % certain that the code is wrong

Comment: Even if the code doesn’t crash, or even if it appears to “work correctly” this is still Undefined Behaviour, and by writing code like this you are storing up problems for yourself (or whoever has the challenge of maintaining such code) which can be extremely difficult to diagnose. Don’t do it.

Comment: I actually find what is happening. When I tried to reach that address after that address has been deallocated, no matter whether compiler  gives errror, that memory address become  available. So,  if you define (for instansce) int a[130] or something, the value previously stored in that address is simply changed by the garbage of  int array. Yet before that, you can still reach the value defined priorly.                    the point is,  compiler is like a protection layer which doesn't allow you to do some specific things that are considered bad.yetthat doesn't mean the memory works like this

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will warn you if you try to return the address directly with `return &x;`

The reason it does not warn you here is because the compiler "doesn't know" that you have assigned the address of a local variable. The compiler is simply not smart enough.

Comment: yet, I can still change the value of that address or assign it by simply derefencing , in case I return a pointer.  if you were right , program should have crashed when I tried to change that value.

Comment: @ozguncan Why should the program necessarily crash?

Comment: because I am trying to reach a deallocated memory location . that's why.

Comment: @ozguncan That does not guarantee a crash